# How to spec controller where model associations occur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm trying to spec the controller code:

```
# ClustersController
def create
  # create new cluster
  @cluster.user = current_user
  # save code
end
```

I am using Rails 3 / RSpec 2 and I'm fairly new to the TDD flow. I basically want to make sure that the user attribute is assigned during the create action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To begin with i don't think you should create, update an save the object. You can pass the user to the create method, like this:

```
Cluster.create(:user => current_user)
```

And to test this you can do:

```
describe ClusterController do
  describe "POST create" do
    it "creates a new cluster" do
      lamda do 
        post :create
      end.should change(Cluster, :count).by(1)
    end

    it "set the current user as the new cluster's user" do
      user = mock()
      Cluster.should_receive(:create).with(:user => user)
      post :create
      assign(:cluster).user.should == user
    end
  end
end
```

I think that will do.

Hope that help.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by I shouldn't "create, update an save the object"? I code I included is part of the ClusterController and it is common to assign the current_user to the association or use current_user.clusters.build

Comment: I mean that you doing this in tree steps: Cluster.new, cluster.user = current_user and finally cluster.save can be done with a single Cluster.create(:user => current_user). It's more simple, and simplifies the tests also.

Comment: Okay, I see what you are saying with that. But, how would I test that the assignment I mentioned in my question has occurred (the way I have it outlined). I'd like to know this anyways for future reference.

Comment: @raidfive: you can check that the controller assigned to the `@cluster` instance variable with `assigns(:cluster)` -- see here in controller specs for an example: https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails

Comment: @zetetic: I want to see if @cluster.user is assigned, not if the controller has assigned @cluster. Thanks for the input though!

Comment: So ... `assigns(:cluster).user.should == `

Comment: You can test it with assigns(:cluster).user.should == user. 
It indeed make it more clear, I will change the post to reflect this.